# MySQL queries slow after a DELETE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two part PHP script.

1. The first that deletes some rows in the database
2. The second that triggers SELECT queries

The second script alone runs in about 0.2 sec. When both parts are processed, the second part takes 5 sec. The next time the second script runs alone, it's back to 0.2 sec.

Any clue?

Comment: I assume that any indexes you have on that table are being rebuilt after the DELETE. Can you post the results of SHOW INDEX FROM mytable?

Comment: If you wait for a few seconds after the delete, does the `SELECT` run quickly? That is, run the delete, wait, then run the select.

Comment: There is actually an index : one primary key. However there is no waiting time between the two parts of the scripts. Is the index rebuilt while the second part runs? is there a way to force index rebuilding before the second part of the script?

Comment: forcing the script to wait between the two parts is not really an option, as the whole script has to run as fast as possible...

Comment: The purpose of the pause was to help determine if reindexing is a likely cause of the problem - it was not intended as a solution. If you can run the delete, wait a while, then run the select, and post the results, that may help determine the cause of the problem. Approximately how many records are being deleted, how many are being selected, and how many records does the table contain?

Comment: OK I tried that. I waited 1 sec, then 5 sec, but it's the same.
Very few records are deleted (around 10), then around 1000 records are selected, among a 30k records table.

Comment: If it's the same after waiting, then reindexing is looking less likely. As seengee suggests, the query cache is a possible candidate. Try running the query a few times with the [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html) option. If it's slow each time, then your query might need tweaking to make it perform better without the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely that the query has cached so it runs faster the second time, [more info here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html). If you add [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html) to the query then you should be able to determine if the cache is a factor.

Comment: I thought of the cache, but it seems like once a query runs fast, the other run faster too...

Answer (score 0):

Your Query-Cache for a table is 'invalidated' each time the table is updated.

The result is that any UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT to your table, will clear the query-cache of that table, and force a fresh disk read for the next SELECT.  The result will be a slower query.

Here's a link to the [MySQL DOCs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-operation.html).

If your table is incredibly large, you may want to investigate MyISAM tables and a separate Key-Cache for yet better read performance.  MyISAM = fast reads, fast writes, horrible concurrency for writes/udpates.  InnoDB = mediocre speed for reads, good concurrency for writes/updates.

-- J Jorgenson --